# How to extract a specific text from gz file?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, fastq

I need to extract the 5 to 11 characters from my fastq.gz data this data is just too large for running in R. So I was wondering if I can do it directly in Linux command line?
The fastq file looks like this:

```
@NB501399:67:HFKTCBGX5:1:11101:13202:1044 1:N:0:CTTGTA
GAGGTNACGGAGTGGGTGTGTGCAGGGCCTGGTGGGAATGGGGAGACCCGTGGACAGAGCTTGTTAGAGTGTCCTAGAGCCAGGGGGAACTCCAGGCAGGGCAAATTGGGCCCTGGATGTTGAGAAGCTGGGTAACAAGTACTGAGAGAAC
+
    AAAAA#EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEAEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEAAAEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEAEEEEEEEEEEEEEEAEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEAE6

@NB501399:67:HFKTCBGX5:1:11101:1109:1044 1:N:0:CTTGTA
TAGGCNACCTGGTGGTCCCCCGCTCCCGGGAGGTCACCATATTGATGCCGAACTTAGTGCGGACACCCGATCGGCATAGCGCACTACAGCCCAGAACTCCTGGACTCAAGCGATCCTCCAGCCTCAGCCTCCCGAGTAGCTGGGACTACAG
+
```

And I only want to extract the 5 to 11 character which located in sequence part (for the first one is TNACGG, for the second is CNACCT) and makes it a new txt file. Can I do that?

Comment: Your latest edit seems invalid. The location of TAGAGG is certainly not in positions 5-11 in the first sequence, and TATAGG is not present in the sample data at all. You should not update to change the requirements drastically after receiving multiple answers, anyway.

Comment: @tripleee I am sry I have some misunderstanding with the fastq file. The CTTGTA is not a part of sequence you are right.

Comment: @tripleee it seems u delet your unswer. Could you show me that again?

Comment: I never posted an answer. JamesBrown appears to have undeleted his, if that's the one you are looking for.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another using `zgrep` and positive lookbehind:

```
$ zgrep -oP "(?<=^[ACTGN]{4})[ACTGN]{6}" foo.gz
TNACGG
CNACCT
```

Explained:

- `zgrep` : `man zgrep`: *search possibly compressed files for a regular expression*
- `-o` *Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line*
- `-P` *Interpret  the  pattern  as  a  Perl-compatible  regular  expression  (PCRE).*
- `(?<=^[ACTGN]{4})` positive lookbehind
- `[ACTGN]{6}` match 6 named characters that are preceeded by above
- `foo.gz` my test file

Comment: I am sorry I made some mistake the goal sequence I wanna to extract for the first one is TAGAGG, for the second is TATAGG.

Comment: It starts at the first line

Comment: I can't even find `TAGAGG` in the whole file.

Comment: Ah, it is on multiple rows. Bailing out until OP gets his question right.

Answer (score 4):

You can use GNU sed with zcat:

```
zcat fastq.gz | sed -n '2~5{s/.\{4\}\(.\{6\}\).*/\1/;p}'
```

- `-n` means lines are not printed by default
- `2~5` means *start with line 2, match every fifth line*
- when the "address" matches, the substitution remembers the fifth to tenth character in `\1` and replaces the whole line with it, `p` prints the result

Comment: Thank you, but your script directly prints the result out. I would like the result is saved as a file. Can I do that?

Comment: Redirect the output to a file `zcat fastq.gz | sed -n '2~5{s/.\{4\}\(.\{6\}\).*/\1/;p}' > outputfile.txt`

Comment: @tripleee: To print the lines after `@`, change it to `sed -n '/^@/{n;s...`

Comment: Thank you but it will also extract some other stuff I will post the result below

Comment: 01399:
ANTTGA
+
A#EEEE
01399:
CNCTGG
+
A#EEEE
01399:
ANGCTC
+

Comment: can we use some code like /^[ATCG]/p or something to select the line which start with ATCT? Thank you

Comment: @Codezy: It works with the sample you provided. If the real data are different, please reflect that in the question.

Comment: /^[ACTG]/ means "line starts with one of A, C, T, and G.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ zcat fastq.gz | awk '(NR%5)==2{print substr($0,5,6)}'
TNACGG
CNACCT
```

Comment: The OP seems to be unfamiliar with U*x basics so you might have to explain how to use `zcat` to extract the compressed data and redirection to write the results to a new file.

Comment: I see that's what the other answers do so - fair enough, done.